# linked list reverse is not working ....?

Tags: java, linked-list

I know it is a minute code. I can't understand why my linked list reversal is not working.
Can some one help fix me my reverse method in the below code.

```
//Reverse a single linked list
public Node reverse()
{
    return reverse(root);
}
private Node reverse(Node node)
{
        Node previous = null;  
        Node current = node;  
        Node forward;  

        while (current != null) 
    {  
            forward = current.next;  
            current.next = previous;  
            previous = current;  
            current = forward;  
        }  
    return previous;  
}
```

Any input on this would be helpful

Thanks !!!

Comment: there are lot of examples. did u google?

Comment: and what s not working? be more descriptive of the behaviour

Comment: 10 -> 20 ->30 is my linked list ... After reverse I get just 10

Comment: Forgetting the recursive part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it should be

```
return root = reverse(root);
```

(Your reverse logic is correct, but if the `root` is still pointing at the old root of the list, you will end up with a 1-element linked list.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming homework...

Write simple tests: list of 0 items, list of 1 items, list of 2 items, list of 10 items. Than make sure each of them work - will narrow down error and learn to write unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Was trying it for practicing it for interviews. Reverse method is Linkedlist class. I have created an object of LinkedList. (LinkedList l1 = new LinkedList();)

Comment: 10 -> 20 ->30 is my linked list ... After reverse I get just 10

Comment: So consider yourself failed the interview with following feedback: missed tests to start with, after getting explicit hint for test did not follow through and still failed to test the code. (Expected comment was something like:"tests for 0,1 items OK, 2 - failed... and here is why...").

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the returned value of reverse() to do your iteration instead of root?